# MySQL JOIN, WHERE and IF issue

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join

i have table of members

```
table members :
pid|  id    | name
1  |  id01  | jenny
2  |  id02  | kain
3  |  id03  | alex
```

and have another table members_opt

```
table members_opt
pid | members_id | category
1   | id01       | cat
2   | id01       | dog
3   | id02       | dog
4   | id03       | NULL
```

now i use below SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM members a JOIN
 (SELECT members_id, max(category) as category FROM members_opt GROUP BY members_id) b
ON a.id = b.members_id
```

But this SQL Query not catch "id03"'s data because "id03"'s members_opt.category is NULL

I want this result

```
result : 
id   | name  | category
id01 | jenny | cat
id02 | kain  | dog
id03 | alex  | NULL
```

(the result now showed double name, double id value.)

How can i use SQL query?

Comment: Please create a SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com so that we can work on your tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

SELECT * FROM members a JOIN
 (SELECT members_id, max(CASE WHEN category IS NULL THEN 0) as category FROM members_opt GROUP BY members_id) b
ON a.id = b.members_id

Comment: Hey NULL does not mean zero it means the value is unknown whereas the zero is itself a value

Comment: @geeksal No, you have not got my point. This will only be in virtual table not in actual just to read the null as this is being ignore this time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to get your desired output -

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.category FROM members a INNER JOIN
 (SELECT members_id, category FROM members_opt GROUP BY members_id) b
ON a.id = b.members_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.category
FROM members a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT members_id, max(category) as category
    FROM members_opt GROUP BY members_id) b
ON a.id = b.members_id
```

and if you want 'cat' for 'jenny', you should use aggregation function `min`.

Comment: Thanks! i have to learn what is different inner join and left join! have a good day Forwad:)